# what is the different from python(numpy.linalg.pinv and scipy.linalg.pinv or scipy.linalg.lstqs) and '/' in matlab?

Tags: python, matlab, least-squares

I sloved a least square problem (Ax=b for A )  using pinv in numpy and (pinv , lstsq) in scipy and "/" in matlab. I got some different answers, so what is the different between them?

problem :Ax=b for A

method:

1. pinv in numpy and scipy : A=b*pinv(x)
2. lstsq in scipy : A.T=lstsq(x.T,b.T) , the problem has changed to (x.T*A.T=b.T)
3. / in matlab : A=b/x

matlab: https://cn.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mrdivide.html

"x = B/A solves the system of linear equations xA = B for x. The matrices A and B must contain the same number of columns. If A is a rectangular m-by-n matrix with m ~= n, and B is a matrix with n columns, then x = B/A returns a least-squares solution of the system of equations xA = B. "

scipy.linalg.lstsq:Compute least-squares solution to equation Ax = b.

scipy.linalg.pinv:Compute the (Moore-Penrose) pseudo-inverse of a matrix.
Calculate a generalized inverse of a matrix using a least-squares solver.

numpy.linalg.pinv:Calculate the generalized inverse of a matrix using its singular-value decomposition (SVD) and including all large singular values.

Comment: Matlab pinv is different than (back)slash also (see [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/39549)). It uses QR rather than SVD.

Comment: Read [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36166625/5211833) on what the backslash operator actually does. The forward slash is a division, which is usually used element wise and not for least squares problems, that's what the backslash is for.

Comment: @Adriaan
"x = B/A solves the system of linear equations x*A = B for x. The matrices A and B must contain the same number of columns. If A is a rectangular m-by-n matrix with m ~= n, and B is a matrix with n columns, then x = B/A returns a least-squares solution of the system of equations x*A = B.

[link](https://cn.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mrdivide.html)