# Matrix multiplication and differences

Tags: matlab, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I need to compute this equation with MATLAB:

[image]

where `Sn` can be both matrices or scalar and I tried to do it with

```
S_A = S_3*S_5*((ones-(S_1*S_5)).^(-1))*S_2+S_4
```

The problem is it doesn't give me the right result and the problem it seems to be with the difference [image] but I cannot figure why is giving me wrong results.

The result is supposed to be this one

[image]

but the MATLAB result is

[image]

I don't understand why the two results are not the same.
The only way that I figured is through this

```
diff = ones-(S_1*S_5);
if S_1*S_5 == zeros         %Perchè senza non funziona?
    diff = ones;
else 
    diff = (ones-(S_1*S_5)).^(-1)
end
S_A = S_3*S_5*diff*S_2+S_4;
```

But I don't think it's a smart solution. Anyone knows why I'm not getting the correct results?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"I tried to do it with `S_A = S_3*S_5*((ones-(S_1*S_5)).^(-1))*S_2+S_4`"

The problem here is that `A^(-1)` in mathematical notation means "take the inverse", whereas you used `A. ^(-1)`, note the dot, which in MATLAB's notation means "take the each matrix element to the power -1". Taking the [inverse of a matrix is not smart in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36166625/5211833) anyway, be it via `inv()` or `^(-1)`, instead, use [`mldivide`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mldivide.html):

```
S_A = S_3*S_5*(eye(size(S_1*S_5,1))-(S_1*S_5))\S_2+S_4
```

Also, as mentioned in [Brice's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53260444/5211833) use `eye`, not `ones` to create an identity matrix, and feed it a size argument as opposed to nothing. All in all it looks to me like you do not have a firm grasp of basic MATLAB functionality, so I'd like to point you to [The MathWorks own tutorial on MATLAB](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/).

Answer (score 4):

`ones` outputs a matrix filled with ones, not the identitiy matrix which is given by function `eye`.
You also need to specify the size of `ones` or `eye`, otherwise it will simply output a scalar `1` (i.e. a 1-by-1 matrix filled with ones, or the 1-by-1 identity matrix).

Try (assuming all matrices have the same size):

```
siz=length(S_1);
S_A = S_3*S_5*((eye(siz)-(S_1*S_5))^(-1))*S_2+S_4
```

Comment: That's exactly what I did, Adriaan. I replaced `.^(-1)` with `^(-1)` because when `S_1*S_5 = 0` the ratio gives a `1/0` problem while with `.^(-1)` I don't have this problem. It seems you solved my problem. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Indeed, I had missed the element-wise operation on my side.